# Create a custom function in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm new to Microsoft Access and need some help.

I'm creating a database and for each record in the last field of the table I need to perform a calculation based on the fields before.
The Calculation is taking the input of each necessary field (which is a string of one of four options), converting it to a number (0,1,2,3) and then taking the sum.
I know how to write the actual code for the calculation in Macros, I'm just not sure how to set up adding my own custom calculation and have it perform on the addition or update of a record.

If someone could help me set this up that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I was taught that you don't store calculated values in databases. You calculate the needed value at the time you use them in a query, report, or form. This can be done easily with a user defined function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a query you create a calculated field.  i.e.Table A has fields F1 and F2. Make query qryA with F1 and F2 ... then create F3
F3: F1 + F2

then you  use qryA for any forms/reports.....